# Taking an array of hex values and putting it into one variable that is either string or an integer?

Tags: c, arrays, string, arduino, hex

Not sure how to do this at all but I have an `uint8_t` array variable that I'd like to get into one string. So,

```
uint8_t uid[] = { 04, 7E, 0B, 72, 44, 34, 84 };
```

I want to get that into a string so it looks like:

```
047E0B72443484
```

I have tried doing:

```
String str = (*char)uid;
```

but printing out str gives me jibberish: ~rD4�8��?

Lastly, I wouldn't be apposed to getting the decimal value representation in one integer as well, either method is fine but I don't know where to start i.e.

an integer with the value: 4126111146852132

The above integer came from converting the hex to dec and appending it together:

```
 - 04 = 4
 - 7E = 126
 - 0B = 11 
 - 72 = 114
 etc...
```

Comment: you need `sprintf`'s `%X` or some such

Comment: Relevant documentation that you should have googled: **sprintf** -- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm

Comment: Is it always 7 characters?

Comment: If you have `4126111146852132`, how will you know whether it came from `4` - `126`, or `41` - `26` ?

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf "%X"` can be used to convert to hex, but it can't do arbitrary sized arrays without some effort. Might as well put that effort into something more direct.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const char* const HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF";

ssize_t to_hex(char* dest, size_t dest_size, const void* src, size_t src_size) {
   if (dest == NULL)
      return src_size*2+1;

   if (dest_size < src_size*2+1)
      return -1;

   while (src_size--) {
      *(dest++) = HEX_CHARS[*((const uint8_t*)src) >> 4];
      *(dest++) = HEX_CHARS[*((const uint8_t*)src) & 0xF];
      src = (const uint8_t*)src + 1;
   }

   *dest = '\0';
   return src_size*2+1;
}
```

Comment: @chux, I originally had `const uint8_t*`, and I missed that line in the conversion. Fixed now. (And fixed a misplaced `const` too. Also added the headers.)

Comment: Downvoted. Generally speaking, using malloc --dynamic memory-- on an **Arduino** is a bad idea, on top of that your function transfers ownership and that isn't even documented. I suggest making it look like `size_t to_hex(const void* in, size_t in_len, char** out, size_t out_len)`, if `out == NULL` the function returns the minimum length it should be to contain the string representation and does nothing else, otherwise it also saves the converted data into `out`. Return `-1` if not enough memory. This way there is no **ownership transfer** and no one is forced to use **dynamic memory**.

Comment: @Patrick Trentin, I wasn't aware that this was for an Arduino, nor of the limitations there; I wrote an easy to use and read function instead. Turns out it's not any harder to use your version (even when allocating memory dynamically) because there's no real need to check the value returned by `to_hex`. (Note: I used "size" instead of "len" since "len" is ambiguous when talking about strings.) (Note: I had to use `ssize_t` to return `-1`.) (Note: It's still undocumented, but the OP is surely going to study it before using it, right?)

Comment: lifted down-vote and reversed it. That was a nice improvement over my suggestion. Sure, the OP is diligent, but the answer is (hopefully) going to stay here for a while and help many more people, so it is guaranteed that sooner or later someone will just *copy-and-paste* it. *IMHO* Arduino tends to attract lots amateurs who lack *general programming basic knowledge* and proceed by *trial and error*, so when doing something so unusual that requires extra care, e.g. like a allocating dynamic memory, there should a big red sign in front of it. Thank you for the edit. :)

Comment: I just realized it doesn't need to be `char** out`. Also made parameter order more consistent with `strncpy` and `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!

For clarity, I wanted this string format "047E0B72443484" because my ultimate goal was to send this data out by JSON (ArduinoJson.h library)

I ultimately accomplished what I was trying to do when I noticed that the JSON library included a function to send an array.

```
JsonArray& uid = root.createNestedArray("UID");
uid.add(testArray[0]);
uid.add(testArray[1]);
uid.add(testArray[2]);
uid.add(testArray[3]);
```

and this allowed me to get a JSON out of:

{ "UID":[4,126,11,114] }

which was exactly what I was trying to do